# Char* combining

Tags: c++, char

I prefer `char*` instead `std::string`, so I wrote a function combining char pointers. I created a new project and tested it. It works fine. But when I try to use it in some larger GUI project, my program crashes.

Here's an example (working) code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

char *StringJoin(const char *String, const char* ...)
{
    va_list ArgList;
    va_start(ArgList, String);
    std::vector<const char *> StringData;
    std::vector<unsigned int> StringLen;
    StringData.push_back(String);
    unsigned int SingleLength = strlen(String);
    StringLen.push_back(SingleLength);
    unsigned int TotalLength = SingleLength;
    while (1)
    {
        const char* Val = va_arg(ArgList, const char*);
        if (!Val)
            break;
        StringData.push_back(Val);
        SingleLength = strlen(Val);
        StringLen.push_back(SingleLength); // In larger projects it crashes here
        TotalLength += SingleLength;
    }
    va_end(ArgList);
    char *NewString = new char[TotalLength + 1];
    unsigned int VectorSize = StringData.size();
    unsigned int NewLength = 0;
    for (unsigned int Element = 0; Element < VectorSize; Element++)
    {
        memcpy(NewString + NewLength, StringData[Element], StringLen[Element]);
        NewLength += StringLen[Element];
    }
    NewString[TotalLength] = '\0';
    StringData.clear();
    StringLen.clear();
    return NewString;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* New = StringJoin("Does ", "it ", "works ", "for ", "you ", "?");
    printf("%s\n", New);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}
```

Is my code safe and stable?

Comment: "I prefer `char*` instead `std::string`" - perhaps you might reconsider your preferences. You'll get far fewer random crashes if you stop juggling pointers and let friendly types manage memory for you.

Comment: As the code won't compile I wouldn't call it working...

Comment: Your code would be about half the size and would be a lot more robust if you stuck to `std::string` instead of trying to use `char *`.

Comment: This is silly, you want to use char* yet are using std::vector? Just use std::string and then call std::string::c_str() when you need a const char* for C APIs.

Comment: why using std::vector? You can as well use std::string...

Comment: `But when I try to use it in some larger GUI project`  And how do you handle the potential memory leaks in this larger GUI app?  You didn't even handle the obvious leak in your posted example.

Comment: Same argument holds for variadic template vs. variadic function. The latter is from good old C times and very unsafe. The former is new in C++11 and improves it a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but never seen such bad code! Using a vector to generate char * is really the obscurest thing I had seen for a long time. And indeed, rewriting existing standard library code is really a very good invest! Why not `string1+string2+string3`?

Comment: Also, the code posted is more than likely dog slow compared to just concatenating `std::string`s.

Comment: @user3786178  Here are the drawbacks to your code  1) it is more than likely much slower than just using std::string and concatenation.  You are using vector's, calling push_back, etc.  That has to have a negative impact on speed  2) it is more maintenance.  You now have to make sure memory is not leaked when using such a function.  3) Someone else looking at your code has to figure out what "StringJoin" does and whether it does it correctly, while std::string concatenation is immediately understood and trusted by practically every C++ programmer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `!Val` condition:

```
const char* Val = va_arg(ArgList, const char*);
if (!Val)
    break;
```

When using variable argument list you need to know **exactly** how many arguments have been passed, or (**update**) when to stop processing the arguments, using e.g. `NULL` / `nullptr` (or any other) [sentinel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

Comment: That's not true. A terminated sequence of arguments is also an option. For example, some of the POSIX `exec...` functions use this convention to pass arguments and environment to child processes. But of course, if you test for a `!Val`, you must supply `nullptr` when invoking the function.

Comment: What if I add NULL as the last argument like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_end/) ?

Comment: Then your condition will be satisfied.

Comment: @user3786178, there's a catch. When you invoke a function whose parameter list ends with an ellipsis, the compiler cannot know which types the corresponding arguments are intended to be, and only does the basic conversion of types. In C++, `NULL` is defined as `0` and thus is an `int` constant, and not a pointer! You won't notice difference on a machine where pointer is same size as `int`. But on an architecture like x64, where pointers re larger than `int`s, your program will be likely to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use variadic templates if your compiler supports it.

The following quite simple function takes an arbitrary number of strings and concatenates it in a loop. It supports both `std::string` and `char*` for the arguments (and even mixed):

```
template<class ...Strings>
std::string StringJoin(Strings ...strings) {
    std::string joined;
    for (auto s : { strings... })
        joined += s;
    return joined;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/Pwr36u)

Now if you want the result to be a `char*`, you need to think about where you allocate the memory and where you deallocate it, i.e. you need to manually manage memory. Unless you use smart pointers:

```
template<class ...Strings>
std::unique_ptr<char[]> StringJoin(Strings ...strings) {
    std::string joined;
    for (auto s : { strings... })
        joined += s;

    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[joined.size() + 1]);
    memcpy(buf.get(), joined.data(), joined.size());
    buf[joined.size()] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/xW9P0e)

Comment: What is the benefit for `StringJoin(a,b,c,d) over `a+b+c+d`? Needs more code, more compile time or more obscure to read :-)

Comment: @Klaus Well, OP wants to have such a function ;)

Comment: You are right! But if he really want's `char *` instead of `std::string` you can't answer with `std::unique_ptr<char>` :-)